# VS Code Refactoring: Change all occurences - but only in block scope

Tags: visual-studio-code, refactoring

When using "change all occurences" in VS Code, it will just search the whole file for matches and change them. Is there a similar feature doing the same thing, but limiting it to function or block scope?

Let's take an example where I would need that: I'm having a React file with several components and want to refactor a class component to a functional component, so I'm changing all occurences of `this.props` to `props`. However, I obviously don't want to change all the other class components as well that are supposed to stay class components. :-)

This seems like such a standard use case, but I'm not able to find it anywhere in VS Code. If it's not possible (yet, or for some good reasons) is there another way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'Add Selection To Next Find Match' functionality. It allows you to highlight the first occurrence you'd like to change, then using a keyboard shortcut, highlight the next occurrence and so on until you've selected all the instances you want to change. When all to-be-changed occurrences are selected, you can edit the selected text normally. Just remember to hit the escape key a couple times after editing to return to a single cursor!

Here are the keybindings for the command, it's Cmd+d on Mac:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

I find it very useful when renaming variables, there's also a shortcut to skip occurrences (Cmd+k Cmd+d) in case there is text you don't want to change in between.

Comment: Cool, thanks! No idea why someone downvoted your response. Probably because it's a workaround. But for now it might be the best way to solve my problem. But I'm not gonna accept your answer just yet because in case there is a proper solution out there - then we both want to know about it. ;-)

Comment: No sweat, definitely a workaround. Leaving it open works for me, I'd like to see something block-scoped too! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

'Rename Symbol' (F2) should do the trick, it works great.